# How do I get the "Ride the lightning" achievement?

Tags: another-case-solved

There's this achievement called "Ride the lightning" which says finish a crime scene search in 2 minutes. Even with the max skills, i don't see how this can be achieve as there are at least more than 2 steps in all crime scene search and you can't reduce your movement to less than 1 minute.

Anyone care to explain how they achieved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, i wasn't looking correctly on google (right keywords) and found a solution but had to search a little. So here's the way to do it:

1. Get the maximum level in Gumshoe stroll (150 candies + 6 stars i think)
2. Ensure you have a Scene photo and a print powder tool
3. Start the Angry Aunt case in chapter 1 and solve it up to the Crime Scene Search
4. In the crime scene search, use the Gumshoe Stroll to move to the living room
5. Use a scene photo to search all objects in the room
6. Use a print powder on the couch to reveal all items in the couch
7. Select the Honeysuckles to finish the case and score Ride the lightning!

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that using the timer tools does work with getting Ride The Lightning. I don't have gumshoe maxed out yet, still one step away so my stroll is at two minutes instead of one.

I started the case, completed up to the crime scene search. You get 45 minutes so i used two +5 minutes tools, moved to the living room using gumshoe and then searched a couple of items(including the honeysuckles) until my timer read 44 minutes. Then i collected the honeysuckles and the achievement popped straight away.

Answer (score -2):

Alternately, just use timer tools (+5 min) to boost your time back up to within 1 minute of the original time.

Comment: I don't think that'll work because they want you to spend 2m or less, not that there are X minute left. I haven't tried it since i scored the achievement but please confirm if it's possible...